# grunt-string-replace: replace string in all files in a directory and its subdirectories

Tags: gruntjs

I would like to replace a string using grunt-string-replace in all files that are in a directory and its subdirectories

For example in all these files:

```
dist/templates_and_modules/templates/template1/template1.php
dist/templates_and_modules/templates/template2/template2.php
dist/templates_and_modules/modules/module1.php
dist/templates_and_modules/modules/module1.php
```

I want to replace

```
/*remove->*/
```

with:

```
/*
```

and

```
/*<-remove*/
```

with

```
*/
```

With explicitly defined files it works:

```
strrep: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/templates_and_modules/templates/template1/template1.php':
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/templates_and_modules/templates/template1/template1.php'
         },
         options: {
             replacements: [
                 {
                     pattern: '/*remove->*/',
                     replacement: '/*'
                 },

                 {
                     pattern: '/*<-remove*/',
                     replacement: '*/'
                 }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

But I can not get it to work with all files in a directory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By trial and error, I found out that this works:

```
files: {
    './': 'dist/**/*.*'
}
```

But I don’t understand, why.

Comment: Rather than providing an object, try providing an array. ['dist/**/*.*'] will find and replace all the files where as 'a':'b' will write b to a with the new changes.

Comment: Yes, it's work for me. I use `'./production/html/': '*.html'` before, and it's not working and no error, I think this plugin can't find the directory with this settings. When I change it to `'./': 'production/html/*.html'`, it's fine.

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to use [globbing patterns](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) to define which files & folders it processes.

See also the [Files section of Configuring Tasks](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks#files)

Something like this:

```
  src: [ '<%= yeoman.app %>/templates_and_modules/**/*.php' ]
  dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/templates_and_modules/'
```

However, that plugin appears to be designed to copy files out to a new destination, not modify them in-place as you are trying to do. Here's a full example that copies them out to a new location:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    'string-replace': {
      dist: {
        src: './app/mylibs/**/*.js',
        dest: './dist/mylibs/',
        options: {
          replacements: [{
            pattern: 'old',
            replacement: 'new'
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-string-replace');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['string-replace']);
};
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to work. Would be cool if someone could post an actual example that works with grunt-string-replace

Comment: @gang What happens now? It doesn't find the files, or the replacement doesn't work correctly on those files? Can you post your latest config?

Comment: I get an error: Warning: Unable to read "dist/templates_and_modules/" file (Error code: EISDIR). Use --force to continue.